# How to refactor method of class with a lot of arguments?

Tags: c#, refactoring

everyone I have a problem with the legacy code in ASP.NET MVC Application,
 in this code there is a class Service in business logic layer. This class has method with 20 arguments this method creates an instance of object using this 20 arguments.
How to refactor this code, because this is a problem when the created objects is changed and it is need to change the arguments in method. 
This service class is used in the controller class and in unit test.
Help me with refactor this code
Thanks in advance.

**EDIT** Additional information:

I can show the signature of the method

```
public Qualification CreateQualification(string achievableCode, string achievableTitle,
        string accreditationRef, bool brandingPrefix, long brand, float guidedLearningHours, 
        int creditValue, long level, long type, long gradingType, long area, int subArea,
        DateTime accreditationStartDate, DateTime accreditationEndDate,
        DateTime lastCertDate, string nameOnCert, 
        long organisationId)
```

I think it is need to apply Kely and Chevex aproach for example I can extract some classes

one will be from parameters:

```
 long area, int subArea
```

other

```
bool brandingPrefix, long brand,
```

And after extract sub classes I can use Introduce Parameter Object I correct understood?

Comment: +1, but when did ASP.Net MVC become legacy :)

Comment: Perhaps he means legacy the same way Michael Feathers does in his book [Working Effectively with Legacy Code (see modern interpretations section)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_code).

Comment: I said legacy code I mean that the code was written by other developers long time ago this code in the ASP.NET MVC application

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Create an object to hold those 20 arguments and pass that object to the method.

For example:

```
public void MyMethod(MyArguments args)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

**EDIT**

While this pattern may be useful for a one-time refactor, if you find yourself using the same arguments in multiple methods, consider [Chevex's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5187049/how-to-refactor-method-of-class-with-a-lot-of-arguments/5187166#5187166) answer.  It's the better approach.

Comment: No, this is known as the [Introduce Parameter Object](http://www.refactoring.com/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) refactoring.

Comment: I was referring to bundling the different parameters into a separate object, but I guess there is no guarantee that they all belong on the same object from an OO perspective.

Comment: This is silly because then you have to set 20 parameters on a separate object. It's the same thing, just abstracted a bit so that the work is on a different object from the original. Instead of bundling them all into one lump, consider my answer of identifying related values and factoring them out. IMO that's better than just cramming all the arguments into an argument object. Pick out data that could potentially go together and factor those into their own objects individually.

Comment: I agree Chevex.  This is the pattern employed by things like event handlers (`EventArgs`, for example.)  True encapsulation is the better route to go down.

Comment: @Chevex - You are right, its likely that that class is doing way too much in the first place. But when red/green refactoring, the easiest change to make is to bundle them into an object. After you green up those tests, look at separating concerns into individual objects, and individual parameters.

Comment: Thank you Kyle, you read my mind about an object context that keeps all parameters. And from my point of view this method appears as result of bad OO Design

Comment: Thank you all as I understood if it is need easy and fast refactor I can use Parameter Object, but if need to implement better refactoring the created class should be separate into sub classes I correct understood?

Comment: Yes Serghei, as you gain experience with the project you are working on, try to identify what values go together and give them their own home in the form of a separate object.

Answer (score 14):

You might try to identify related data in the arguments and factor them into their own custom objects. For example, pretend you have this object:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int age,
        string streetAddress, string city, string state, int zipCode)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.Age = age;
        this.StreetAddress = streetAddress;
        this.City = city;
        this.State = state;
        this.ZipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Try refactoring this to be two classes, extracting the related address info into its own class and then adding that object as a property of the original object:

```
public class Person
{
    public Person(string firstName, string lastName, int age, Address address)
    {
        this.FirstName = firstName;
        this.LastName = lastName;
        this.Age = age;
        this.Address = address;
    }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public Address Address { get; set; }
}

public class Address
{
    public Address(string streetAddress, string city, string state, int zipCode)
    {
         this.StreetAddress = streetAddress;
         this.City = city;
         this.State = state;
         this.ZipCode = zipCode;
    }

    public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int ZipCode { get; set; }
}
```

Without more information I'd say this is your best approach.

Comment: Chevex- Thank you this is a good idea to extract sub classes but problem is that I don't know how exactly group parameters in different classes.

Comment: You are welcome. And I suppose that would be a question you'd have to answer through experience and communication with the domain expert on the project.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [Builder](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern) pattern

```
QualificationBuilder builder = new QualificationBuilder();
builder.setAchievableCode(achievableCode)
       .setAchievableTitle(achievableTitle)...
Qualification = builder.build();
```

Comment: This is a good approach but from 20 parameters 8 is mandatory fields for create an object of Qualification. How this implement with builder?